# How would you make the following doubling function more efficient and cleaner?

Tags: python

I just wrote a simple function which takes any integer and continually summing up all the digits in it until it reaches a length of a single digit.
I wonder if there more nicer way to reformat that function?

```
def summing(number):
    number_length = len(str(number))
    sum_of_digits = number
    while number_length > 1:
        sum_of_digits = 0
        for digit in str(number):
            sum_of_digits += int(digit)
        number_length = len(str(sum_of_digits))
        number = sum_of_digits
    return sum_of_digits
```

Example:

```
number = 132456 => 1+3+2+4+5+6 => 4+6+5+6 => 10 + 11 => 1 + 2 => 3
```

Comment: `while number > 9: number = sum(int(x) for x in str(number))`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: _until it reach a length long digit_ What is "a length long digit"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write it using [casting out nines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines):

```
def summing(number):
    return number % 9 or 9

number = 132456
summing(number)
# 3
```

...assuming a number greater than zero.

If you want it to handle all integers, you will need to deal with zero and convert negative numbers to positive by taking the absolute value ([`abs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs)).

```
def summing(number):
    if number == 0: return 0
    return abs(number) % 9 or 9

number = -1234
summing(number)
# 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark,
look like much simpler than the original one, I just added another if statement to determine if the length of the number is 1 or higher
`
def summing2(number):
    if number == 0: return 0
    if len(str(number)) == 1:
        return number
    return abs(number) % 9 or 9
`